# scala macros generating implicits

Tags: scala, macros, implicit, scala-macros

I am trying to generate some implicits via a macro -the condensed version of the macro looks like this:

```
object Implicits {
  def generate(c:Context):c.Expr[Unit]={
    import c.universe._
    c.Expr[Unit] {
      q"""
           object Dud{
            implicit val p:java.io.File = new java.io.File("/tmp")
             def toString():String ={ "Dud here" }
          }
          import Dud._
      """
    }
  }
}
```

I am using the macro:

```
object ImplicitTest extends App {
  def genImplicits = macro Implicits.generate
  genImplicits
  val f: File = implicitly[File]
  println(f)
}
```

The test bails out complaining that

```
ImplicitTest.scala could not find implicit value for parameter e: java.io.File
[error]   val f: File = implicitly[File]
[error]                           ^
```

What am I doing wrong with this macro?

Comment: Based on @Travis Brown's suggestion -I wrote the annotation macro: This one works -Adding it as an answer as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call to the macro method will be expanded to something like this (I generated this text by printing the expression before returning it, and after adding an `override` to the `toString` definition):

```
{
  object Dud extends scala.AnyRef {
    def <init>() = {
      super.<init>();
      ()
    };
    implicit val p: java.io.File = new java.io.File("/tmp");
    override def toString(): String = "Dud here"
  };
  import Dud._;
  ()
}
```

Note that this doesn't bring anything into scope in the body of `ImplicitTest`. Both the `Dud` object and the import are inside a block, and neither are available by the time you get to the `val f: File = implicitly[File]` line.

You can write an [implicit macro method](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/implicits.html), or you can write a [macro annotation](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/annotations.html) that you could apply to `ImplicitTest` that would add both `Dud` and the import, but you can't introduce new objects or imports into scope with a `def` macro.

Answer (score 4):

Based on Travis's answer (Thank you) I wrote the macro using macro annotation: Here is the code if it helps someone else -it's proof of concept

```
@compileTimeOnly("enable macro paradise to expand macro annotations")
class defaultFileMacro extends StaticAnnotation {
  def macroTransform(annottees: Any*) = macro DefaultMacro.impl
}

object DefaultMacro {
  def impl(c: Context)(annottees: c.Expr[Any]*): c.Expr[Any] = {
    import c.universe._
    val inputs:List[Tree] = annottees.map(_.tree).toList
     val tree= inputs(0)
     val q"val $list:List[$t]= $files" = tree
      print(show(q"""implicit val fl1:$t = $files(0)"""))
     c.Expr[Any] {
     q"""
            implicit val fl1:$t = $files(0)
      """
    }
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
object ImplicitTest extends App {
  def findDefaultFile() = {
    @defaultFileMacro val list: List[File] = List(new File("/tmp"))
    val f: File = implicitly[File]
    println(f)
  }
  findDefaultFile()
}
```

run

```
> run-main ImplicitTest
[info] Running ImplicitTest 
/tmp
```